# Child tab with NO target attribute in Cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress

I got a really tough issue while writing the scripts in Cypress.
I clicked an element and it directs to a new page.
I want to click the next element on the new page.
I know that Cypress doesn't allow to work on a new window simultaneously.

So I tried solving with many solutions available in the web.

I got the same error that it could not click the element on the new tab.
I have attached the html body of the screen.
Can someone please help me out to solve the issue.

[image: This is the html body]

```
The following was my code..

/// <reference types="cypress" />

describe('ship test',() =>{
it('first test',() =>{
cy.viewport(1120,800)
cy.visit('url')
cy.get('#LoginForm-login_authname').type('12345)
cy.get('#LoginForm-login_authid').type('12345{enter}')

cy.on('uncaught:exception', (err, runnable) => {
return false
})

cy.wait[cy.xpath('//span[normalize-space()="Work"]')
.click({force: true})]

cy.xpath('//*[@id="VTK-j_idt1184"]',{timeout : 700000}).click()
cy
.window().then((win) => {
cy.spy(win, 'open').as('redirect');
});
cy
.xpath('//a[@class="ui-commandlink ui-widget btn_wrapper pull-right createtask_btn"]',{timeout : 700000})
.click();
cy
.get('@redirect')
.should('be.calledWith', 'href', '/about');
})
})
```

The error..
[image: This is the image]`enter code here`

Comment: What is the error that you are getting. And also add your code that you wrote to the question.

Comment: I updated brother..Can u pls guide me to get the solution.I need the control of new tab.May be by loading the new tab in the same previous tab orelse in someother ways..

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this

```js
cy.xpath('//*[@id="VTK-j_idt1184"]',{timeout : 700000}).click()
```

and this

```js
cy.xpath('//a[@class="ui-commandlink ui-widget btn_wrapper pull-right createtask_btn"]',{timeout : 700000})
.click();
```

are trying to click the same link.

Try removing the 1st one. (you need to click after the spy is set).

To test the new tab, is easiest to visit in a new test.

```js
it('tests the about tab', () => {
  cy.visit('/about');
  ...
```

**Footnote**

If `click()` does not work, you may have more luck trying `.realClick()`.

See [Cypress Real Events](https://github.com/dmtrKovalenko/cypress-real-events) written by Dmitriy Kovalenko (Ukraine).

Comment: No it doesnt work...

Comment: I tried alternaively the invoke method in the above script by removing the spy method.There was no target attribute.So i tried removing the 'onclick' attribute,and it works a little bit doesnt execute properly.The new tab doesnt open as I wish but the elements of the new page were not loaded.Can you give me more suggestions

Comment: I'm not sure how the `target attribute` is involved (not following what you describe in the comment). I think the reason the reason you get a message saying "element is detached from DOM" is because your test clicked the link once, then it tries to click it again but the page is changing (so button is now "detached"). It's purely a guess.

Comment: One other thing, use `cy.stub(win, 'open').as('redirect')` instead of `cy.spy(win, 'open').as('redirect')` to stop the redirect from happening. Then test from the new link in a new test using `cy.visit('/about')`.

Comment: Note it may not even be using `window.open()` - it's hard to tell with all the CIA redaction going on there.

Comment: ok brother..let me try ..thanks for ur support